# Two issues - saving changes in an instantiated workbook, and activating other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have two spreadsheets; I'll call them spreadsheet 1 and spreadsheet 2. Spreadsheet one has a function which generates days of the month, and if it's at the end of the month, it is trying to call the module/sub in spreadsheet 2. This is to generate both "daily" reports and "monthly" reports.

At this point, there are two errors: the first is when I am trying to save the new instance of spreadsheet 2 that I created. The error is that it asks to save the workbook in a macro-free format. I simply want to save it! Not to make any changes to formatting. I am not even sure that it is trying to save changes to the instantiated book object.

the second is in spreadsheet 2, even though I set it to be active sheet (I think), the activesheet still comes up as the worksheet on spreadsheet 1 that runs the macro in the first place.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    Option Explicit
Public Function LastWeekOfMonth() As Boolean

'finds the current date
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    CurrentDate = CDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, 1))

'find filepath and filename of the monthly documentation file
    Dim mFilePath As String
    Dim mFileName As String

    mFilePath = "F:\Project Sweep\Kim Checklist\Barry Polinsky\Brathwaite, Tamika\"
    mFileName = Cells(3, 4) & ".m_d.xlsm"

     'if it is the last week of the month, write a monthly report, and return true to continue with the face to face paperwork
     If (31 - Day(CurrentDate)) <= 7 Then
        'write a monthly report
        Dim app As New Excel.Application
        Dim book As Excel.Workbook

      '  app.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary
        Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(mFilePath & mFileName)

        'run the subroutine CheckSpreadsheet in module WriteReport in target book
        app.Run "'" & mFilePath & mFileName & "'!" & "WriteReport" & ".CheckSpreadsheet", book
      '  CheckSpreadsheet (book)




        'error next line
        book.Save
        book.Close

        app.Quit
        Set app = Nothing
        LastWeekOfMonth = True

    'if it is not, simply continue with the face to face paperwork
     Else
        LastWeekOfMonth = False
     End If

End Function
```

In the target worksheet, in module WriteReport, subroutine CheckSpreadsheet, the following code is located.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckSpreadsheet(wbook As Excel.Workbook)


    Set wosheet = wbook.Sheets("Monthly")

wosheet.Cells(5, 5) = "Hello world!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're opening a second instance of `Excel.Application` if the code you are running is in Excel VBA?

Comment: the hope was to be able to open up workbook 2 and not have it become visible. I was advised by other posts here on stackoverflow that the way to do this is to open a new application as the workbook object does not have a .visible property

Comment: Okay fair enough. The issue may lie with the fact that you are using `Application.Run` to call your `CheckSpreadsheet` subroutine which will initiate from your first instance of Excel, you are then passing an `Excel.Workbook` variable that is open in your second instance of Excel. Try replacing `Application.Run` with `app.Run` so it runs the subroutine from your second instance of Excel

Comment: ^ that. `wbook.Activate` is trying to activate a workbook that is in another Excel instance. ...but why would you `.Activate` anything anyway? Also drop the parentheses around the `MsgBox` arguments: `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name`.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. The only issue remaining is that the macro in spreadsheet 2 doesn't seem to do anything; the wosheet.Cells(5, 5) = "Hello world!" - see updated code

Comment: Issue here is workbook was being opened as read only. Issue resolved. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Trying to save a ReadOnly file gives a Run-time error 1004. It seems that there is an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere before calling `LastWeekOfMonth` see [Debugging and Troubleshooting](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to have another instance of Excel, the property to hide a workbook is `Windows`, in order to hide the excel windows used by the workbook. Also bear in mind that a workbook can have more than one window.

If you are sure that the workbook you want to hide has only one window use this line:

```
Workbooks("WbkName").Windows(1).Visible = False
```

If the workbook has several windows use this procedure:

```
Sub Wbk_Hide()
Dim wbk As Workbook, wdw As Window
    Set wbk = Workbooks("WbkName")   'Update as required
    For Each wdw In wbk.Windows
        wdw.Visible = False
    Next
End Sub
```

I believe this changes the scope of your procedures, let me know otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments, and your help so far on this. Your way works, I'm only having trouble making sure that I can close out of all of the workbooks and applications that I open, so I'm not going to go with it for now. The issue remaining is that the macro in spreadsheet 2 doesn't seem to do anything; the wosheet.Cells(5, 5) = "Hello world!" - see updated code